# Getting PID value over SSH, doesn't work until exit

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, pid

I would like to start `mbuffer` in listening mode on a remote server, so I do

```
ssh -f root@10.10.10.46 'mbuffer -4 -v 0 -q -I 8023 > /tmp/mtest & echo $!'
```

and it outputs the `PID` number, which I would like to save in `$pidValue`, but if I do

```
pidValue=$(ssh -f 10....)
```

then it doesn't exit until the `mbuffer` process exits.

**Question**

How do I get the PID value from the `mbuffer` process?

Comment: My understanding was that your mbuffer process produces it. If no, you need a way to get it from the process.  bash variable $$ won't help you here, Backgrounding the process, and grabbing the PID from there, may be a way. fgrep or similar is problably too unreliable, as it's harder to identify the specific process you want to refer to, in case it has been started multiple times. daemontools may offer something helpful there, but i'd have to look at the man page myself

Comment: using coproc  may be a way too:   coproc mbuffer -4 -v 0 -q -I 8023; echo $COPROC_PID - it seems a bit overkill but reducing complexity with a functional nonoptimal solution is preferable to having no solution, IMHO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before running the process which uses the remote PID, scp the remote file to local storage, from where you deal with it as you like.

it seems that this construct:

```
read -r var < <(ssh remote "echo test; sleep 5") ; echo $var
```

can give you results earlier, but that may depend on the remote process you're starting. Try that.